# How does a linear synchronous motor work? (Maglev)

Tags: electromagnetism

I am finding it difficult to understand the workings of the linear synchronous motor (LSM) that is used in maglev trains. Specifically, I cannot visualise how the moving magnetic field is created by the three phase current.

I think that I have understood how a normal non-linear synchronous motor works with the help of a video, but have not been able to find a similar video or animation for a linear one.

Additionally, I'm confused about how the motor is used the propel maglev trains. I thought that the synchronous motor worked by a pole of the moving magnetic field attracting a pole of the rotor and pulling it along. However, this does not seem to match with thisdiagram I have been seeing around everywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]